# Unbind ng-click for dynamic dom element in angular

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-click

I have a dynamic div which is conditionally pushed into the dom. I have an ng-click event bound to a child element inside the div which fires myfunc() . Now when that div is removed and re-added to the dom , myfunc() is fired two times. myfunc is called the number of times div has been removed and re-added. It looks like i need to unbind the ng-click even on the child element.

```
 <div gm-info-window="infoWindow" gm-on-closeclick="infoWindowClosed()"> 
        <div> 
          <b>{{category}}</b>
          <p>{{subcategory}}</p>
          <b ng-show="dateString != null"> {{dateString}}</b>
          <p >{{place}}</p>
          <a ng-show="hasDescription != false" ng-click="myfunc()">View Description</a>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How do you add this dynamic div into DOM?

Comment: i am not adding it directly..the infowindow is actually added by a third party api

Comment: @Chandermani : i just checked , i call $compile everytime to compile the contents of infowindow before pushing it into the dom.can it cause problem

Comment: Yes, that could be the issue. Once you compile the content, keep the reference to the link function. When you want to push it into dom, call it with the scope parameter and the issue would be fixed.

Comment: i see that its already been done. here is the code
infoWindow.open = function open(map, anchor) {
      $compile(element.contents())(scope);
        _open.call(infoWindow, map, anchor);
      };

Comment: This seems to be compiling the code again on each `open` call. Store the results of `$compile(element.contents())` in variable outside the function and in the function just do the binding to scope.

Comment: Hi i have the exact same problem :(. Is there a way to UNcompile the button please ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a potential of memory leak by inserting a dom dynamically using $compile. 
An existing dom can be replaced with the new dom element while the scopes associated with the old dom is still there, which means all watches and event listeners are still there.

The safe way is:

1. Create a new child scope for the dom we are going to insert dynamically.
2. Check to see if dom is going to replace an existing one. And destroy existing scope associated with it first.
3. Compile new dom using new child scope as parameter.

Something like this:

```
var newScope = parentScope.$new(),      //parentScope is the scope you are going to add dom under it
    $el=$(content);  

if ($el) {                              //same dom already exist?
    var existingScope = $el.scope();    //any scope associated?

    if (existingScope) {
          existingScope.$destroy();
    }
}
$compile(content)(newScope);
```

References: http://roubenmeschian.com/rubo/?p=51
http://makandracards.com/makandra/15851-angularjs-access-the-scope-for-a-rendered-dom-element